# How to use single quotes with expect -c "send ..."

Tags: php, expect

This works as expected:

```bsh
$ expect -c 'send "one two three"'
one two three
```

This however doesn't:

```bsh
$ expect -c "send 'one two three'"
usage: send [args] string
    while executing
"send 'one two three'"
```

The problem is that I want to use the PHP function [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to create safe arguments for passing to `send`, but this function has no option to return double-quoted strings, only single-quoted. So I'd like to make the second option work. Is there a way to make it work with `send`?

---

**Edit**: as requested, here's a PHP sample:

```php
$password = escapeshellarg($password);

$cmd = <<<CMD
    expect -c 'spawn /var/www/bin/helium-wallet create basic;
    expect "Password";
    send $password;
    send "\\n";
    expect "Confirm";
    send $password;
    send "\\n";
    expect eof'
CMD;
```

Comment: err, where are you putting the string, exactly? in the PHP program I mean. You have the string `send "one two three"` that you want to pass as arg to `expect`, so if you pass it through the shell, then wouldn't quoting with single quotes to `'send "one two three"'` be the simple solution and do exactly what you want? (The double-quoted alternative would be `"send \"one two three\""` but it has no advantage over the single-quoted one)

Comment: remember the string/program/stuff you pass to expect (`send "whatever"`) isn't in the shell language, it's in TCL. So, if you're using `escapeshellarg()` to add the quotes around that, then that's wrong.

Comment: @ilkkachu I just want to escape what I pass to `send`, not the entire thing I pass to `expect -c`. Sorry if that wasn't clear, I think I have to update the question. Thanks for mentioning TCL, I wasn't aware of that. I guess that's the reason why I can't make it work.

Comment: can you show a bit more of what you have there? E.g. something like `$y = escapeshellarg($x)` maybe, but what's in `$x` and what do you do with `$y` next (some call to `system()` maybe) etc.?

Comment: The problem is that [Tcl gives no special meaning to single quotes](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) -- they are just ordinary characters. `expect -c "send 'one two three'"` is giving send **3** arguments (`'one`, `two`, and `three'`), hence the error. Tcl syntax is not shell syntax, so the PHP function is giving you wrong data for Expect.

Comment: @ilkkachu I've added a PHP sample, however, after reading the comments I guess it's just how it works with TCL. For now I was able to skip the escaping and limit the characters the password can consist of. If I ever need to escape arbitrary password, I'll see if maybe escapeshellcmd instead of escapeshellarg can help.